# Gson make firebase-like json from objects

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gson

In the past a manually created as list of data, which was stored locally in a database. Now I would like to parse those data and put them through **import json** option into firebase dbs, but what I get doesn't look like firebase generated json.

What I get is:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"id_1",
      "text":"some text"
    },
    {  
      "id":"id_2",
      "text":"some text2"
    },
    ...
]
```

what I want is something like this:

```
{  
   "id_1": {  
      "text":"some text",
      "id":"id_1"
    },
    "id_2":{  
      "text":"some text2",
      "id":"id_1"
    },
    ...
}
```

my Card class

```
class Card{
    private String id;
    private String text;

}
```

retrieving data

```
//return list of card
List<Card> cards =myDatabase.retrieveData();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = gson.toJson(cards);
```

So how I can I achieve this (it looks to me) dynamically named properties for json that look like those generated by firebase ?

**EDIT:**
I found that gson has FieldNamingStrategy interface that can change names of fields. But it looks to me it's not dynamic as I want.

**EDIT2**
my temp fix was to just override toString()

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return "\""+id+"\": {" +
                     "\"text\":" + "\""+text+"\","+
                     "\"id\":" +"\""+ id +"\","+
                     "\"type\":"+ "\""+ type +"\""+
             '}';
    }
```

Comment: If you try to serialize a List, then you'll get an array back in the JSON.  You'll have to compose something that's not a List.

Comment: Why do you want an object with numbered keys anyway?

Comment: @cricket_007 `new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject().get(id)`

Comment: Sure, but if it's a sequentially ordered list, you can use a JsonArray to access the same thing

Comment: @cricket_007 I have String id, also I only had experience with this type of accessing data from firebase, I will rethink my stance, thanks. What are main benefits of your approach

Comment: You have a list of objects. It's not clear what ID you want, but if it's a number, you treat it like a regular list object, not a map of key value pairs

Comment: @cricket_007 if I want to edit property of DBS object I use something like this. `FirebaseDBS.instace().getReference("cards").child(id).child("text").setValue("Hallo");` I wouldn't be able to achieve this wihout knowing position in list

Answer (score 2):

Your "temp fix" will store each object as a string not a object.

You need to serialize an object to get that data, not a list.

For example, using a Map

```
List<Card> cards = myDatabase.retrieveData();
Map<Map<String, Object>> fireMap = new TreeMap<>();
int i = 1;
for (Card c : cards) {
    Map<String, Object> cardMap = new TreeMap<>();
    cardMap.put("text", c.getText());
    fireMap.put("id_" + (i++), cardMap);
}
Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = gson.toJson(fireMap);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, feels better than my temp. solution :)