# Need help converting Firebase data to Java Object for use in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have read tons of reports and questions on this subject and can't seem to figure this out. I have a Java Object Class called Yard:

```
public class Yard {
    private String id;
    private String location;
    private long hives;
    private String last_visit;
    private String photo_url;
    private String yard_type;

    public Yard(String id, String location, long hives, String last_visit, String photo_url, String yard_type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.location = location;
        this.hives = hives;
        this.last_visit = last_visit;
        this.photo_url = photo_url;
        this.yard_type = yard_type;
    }

    public Yard() {

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public long getHives() {
        return hives;
    }

    public void setHives(long hives) {
        this.hives = hives;
    }

    public String getLast_visit() {
        return last_visit;
    }

    public void setLast_visit(String last_visit) {
        this.last_visit = last_visit;
    }

    public String getPhoto_url() {
        return photo_url;
    }

    public void setPhoto_url(String photo_url) {
        this.photo_url = photo_url;
    }

    public String getYard_type() {
        return yard_type;
    }

    public void setYard_type(String yard_type) {
        this.yard_type = yard_type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Yard{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", location='" + location + '\'' +
                ", hives=" + hives +
                ", last_visit='" + last_visit + '\'' +
                ", photo_url='" + photo_url + '\'' +
                ", yard_type='" + yard_type + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And I am trying to retrieve the user's yards to display them in a recyclerview.

Here is (up to this point) my method for retrieval:

```
 private List<Yard> getYards(){
        final List<Yard> list = new ArrayList<>();
        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Log.d(TAG,"Getting to getYards()" + userID);
        FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference dbRef = db.getReference().child(getString(R.string.dbname_yards));
        Query query = dbRef.child(userID);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Yard y = new Yard();
                        y = dataSnapshot.getValue(Yard.class);
                        list.add(y);
                        Log.e(TAG,""+y.toString());
                    }
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

       return list;
    }
```

I have commented out the recyclerview layout manager and adapter because I just can't seem to get the data as my Yard Object.

The errors I am currently receiving are:

```
12-28 15:29:24.109 4984-4984/com.bkbeesites.hivelog W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for yard2 found on class com.bkbeesites.hivelog.Models.Yard
12-28 15:29:24.109 4984-4984/com.bkbeesites.hivelog W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for yard1 found on class com.bkbeesites.hivelog.Models.Yard
12-28 15:29:24.109 4984-4984/com.bkbeesites.hivelog E/YardsFragment: Yard{id='null', location='null', hives=0, last_visit='null', photo_url='null', yard_type='null'}
12-28 15:29:24.109 4984-4984/com.bkbeesites.hivelog W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for yard2 found on class com.bkbeesites.hivelog.Models.Yard
12-28 15:29:24.109 4984-4984/com.bkbeesites.hivelog W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for yard1 found on class com.bkbeesites.hivelog.Models.Yard
12-28 15:29:24.109 4984-4984/com.bkbeesites.hivelog E/YardsFragment: Yard{id='null', location='null', hives=0, last_visit='null', photo_url='null', yard_type='null'}
```

[This is my data structure. I manually added these yards and also would like to know if when I am at the point where the user is adding yards, do I need to generate a key as the names?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdJNv.jpg)

Sorry if this was an annoying newbie question, but I'm stumped. Thanks, in advance, for any help.

Comment: this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847886/2552917

Answer (score 0):

You're using `dataSnapshot` instead of `ds`. That is, you're trying to create a yard from the `uid` ref instead of the individual `yard[#]` refs when iterating over the `uid` ref's children. So it should be

```
Yard y = ds.getValue(Yard.class);
```

PS: `foo_bar` is ugly.  The standard is to use `fooBar`.